# função max tirar top10

Tags: mysql, sql, query, order-by

primeiro estou tentando tirar o max dessa query.

```
select case 
  when len(convert(varchar, mes)) = 1 
    then '0' + convert(varchar, mes) + convert(varchar, ano)
  else
    convert(varchar, mes) + convert(varchar, ano)
end as mes_ano,
--(select max(mes_ano) from tbl_caixa_saldo)
from tbl_caixa_saldo
where empresa = 'MAT'.
```

depois preciso verificar a data maximo dela e pegar o top 10 do mes seguinte.

```
select top 10 tbl_funcionarios.nome as label,
        sum(tbl_caixa_menor.valor*-1) as value
from tbl_caixa_menor,tbl_funcionarios,tbl_departamentos, tbl_tipo_caixa
   where tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios = tbl_funcionarios.cod_funcionarios
          and tbl_funcionarios.cod_departamento = tbl_departamentos.codigo
          and tbl_tipo_caixa.nome = tbl_caixa_menor.tipo
          and tbl_caixa_menor.empresa = 'MAT'
          and tbl_caixa_menor.dataTransacao BETWEEN (DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) AND convert(date,getdate())
   group by tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios, tbl_funcionarios.nome
   having sum (tbl_caixa_menor.valor) <0
   order by  value desc
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando uma versão presumida de `tbl_caixa_saldo`, `tbl_funcionarios` e `tbl_caixa_menor`, adicionada ao final e detalhada em [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fZgfxPRWnQ4UT1gJBfUpnz/1),

para buscar ano e mês mais recente de `tbl_caixa_saldo`, combinaria mês com ano no formato de data, ajustando mês de 1 dígito por [lpad](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_lpad.asp):

```
select 
    max(date(concat(ano, '-', lpad(mes, 2, '0'), '-01'))) data_mais_recente
from tbl_caixa_saldo
where empresa = 'MAT';
```

Dado que o valor retornado é escalar, esse código pode ser usado como parâmetro na query principal, entre parênteses, como subquery.

Caso a versão de MySQL utilizada seja a partir da 8.0, pode ser usada uma [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) para construir a lista completa do par (label, value) para todos os funcionários,

e selecionar entre as [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) `rank()` ou `dense_rank()` para definir uma linha de corte, considerando eventuais empates.

Deixando como comentários a `classificacao_arbitraria_de_empates` e o `ranking_descontando_empates`, a query abaixo traz a versão Top 10 funcionários por classificação generosa, aplicando `ranking_sem_desconto_de_empates`:

```
with lista_completa as (
select 
    tbl_funcionarios.nome as label
    , sum(tbl_caixa_menor.valor*-1) as value
from tbl_caixa_menor, tbl_funcionarios
where tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios = tbl_funcionarios.cod_funcionarios
  and tbl_caixa_menor.empresa = 'MAT'
  and date_format(tbl_caixa_menor.dataTransacao, '%Y-%m-01') = date_add((select max(date(concat(ano, '-', lpad(mes, 2, '0'), '-01'))) from tbl_caixa_saldo where empresa = 'MAT'), interval 1 month)
group by tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios, tbl_funcionarios.nome
having sum(tbl_caixa_menor.valor) < 0
order by value desc
)
, lista_completa_com_ranking as (
select
    label
    , value
    --, row_number() over (order by value desc) classificacao_arbitraria_de_empates
    --, rank() over (order by value desc) ranking_descontando_empates
    , dense_rank() over (order by value desc) ranking_sem_desconto_de_empates
from lista_completa
)
select * from lista_completa_com_ranking
where ranking_sem_desconto_de_empates <= 10;
```

**tbl_caixa_saldo**

| empresa | mes | ano |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MAT | 1 | 2021 |
| MAT | 2 | 2021 |
| MAT | 3 | 2021 |
| MAT | 4 | 2021 |
| MAT | 5 | 2021 |
| MAT | 6 | 2021 |
| MAT | 7 | 2021 |
| MAT | 8 | 2021 |
| MAT | 9 | 2021 |
| MAT | 10 | 2021 |
| MAT | 11 | 2021 |
| MAT | 12 | 2021 |
| MAT | 1 | 2022 |
| outra | 1 | 2021 |
| outra | 2 | 2021 |
| outra | 3 | 2021 |
| outra | 4 | 2021 |
| outra | 5 | 2021 |
| outra | 6 | 2021 |
| outra | 7 | 2021 |
| outra | 8 | 2021 |
| outra | 9 | 2021 |
| outra | 10 | 2021 |
| outra | 11 | 2021 |
| outra | 12 | 2021 |
| outra | 1 | 2022 |
| outra | 2 | 2022 |

**tbl_funcionarios**

| cod_funcionarios | nome | cod_departamento |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10000000 | Fulano de Tal (0) | 101 |
| 10000001 | Fulano de Tal (1) | 101 |
| 10000002 | Fulano de Tal (2) | 101 |
| 10000003 | Fulano de Tal (3) | 101 |
| 10000004 | Fulano de Tal (4) | 101 |
| 10000005 | Fulano de Tal (5) | 101 |
| 10000006 | Fulano de Tal (6) | 101 |
| 10000007 | Fulano de Tal (7) | 101 |
| 10000008 | Fulano de Tal (8) | 102 |
| 10000009 | Fulano de Tal (9) | 102 |
| 10000010 | Fulano de Tal (10) | 102 |
| 10000011 | Fulano de Tal (11) | 103 |
| 10000012 | Fulano de Tal (12) | 103 |

**tbl_caixa_menor**

| dataTransacao | empresa | tipo | cod_funcionarios | valor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 | outra | saída do estoque | 10000012 | -273482.29 |
| 2022-02-02 | outra | saída do estoque | 10000012 | -545000 |
| 2022-02-03 | outra | saída do estoque | 10000011 | -23000 |
| 2022-02-04 | outra | saída do estoque | 10000011 | -102000 |
| 2022-02-04 | outra | saída do estoque | 10000000 | -1000 |
| 2022-02-04 | outra | saída do estoque | 10000001 | -1000 |
| 2022-02-05 | outra | saída do estoque | 10000002 | -1000 |
| 2022-02-01 | outra | saída do estoque | 10000003 | -1000 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | entrada no estoque | 10000004 | -5000 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | entrada no estoque | 10000004 | 1000 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | entrada no estoque | 10000005 | -1000 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | entrada no estoque | 10000006 | -1000 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | entrada no estoque | 10000007 | -1000 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | entrada no estoque | 10000008 | -1000 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | entrada no estoque | 10000009 | -600 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | entrada no estoque | 10000010 | -500 |
| 2022-01-01 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000012 | -273482.29 |
| 2022-02-02 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000012 | -545000 |
| 2022-02-03 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000011 | -23000 |
| 2022-02-04 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000011 | -102000 |
| 2022-02-04 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000000 | -1000 |
| 2022-02-04 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000001 | -1001 |
| 2022-02-05 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000002 | -1002 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000003 | -1002 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000004 | -1000 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000005 | -1005 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000006 | -1000 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000007 | -1000 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000008 | -1008 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000009 | -600 |
| 2022-02-01 | MAT | saída do estoque | 10000010 | -510 |

Answer (score 0):

Modificação da query acima para versões sem suporte a CTE e window functions, [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mStPdpzHbaXLHBDRtM3Cjc/0) em MySQL v5.7:

**Equivalente a row_number(), `classificacao_arbitraria_de_empates`**

```
select * from (
select
    label
    , value
    , @curRn := @curRn + 1 as row_number
from (
select
  tbl_funcionarios.nome as label
  , sum(tbl_caixa_menor.valor*-1) as value
  , (select @curRn := 0) r
from tbl_caixa_menor, tbl_funcionarios
where tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios = tbl_funcionarios.cod_funcionarios
  and tbl_caixa_menor.empresa = 'MAT'
  and date_format(tbl_caixa_menor.dataTransacao, '%Y-%m-01') = date_add((select max(date(concat(ano, '-', lpad(mes, 2, '0'), '-01'))) from tbl_caixa_saldo where empresa = 'MAT'), interval 1 month)
group by tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios, tbl_funcionarios.nome
having sum(tbl_caixa_menor.valor) < 0
order by value desc
) a
) b
where row_number <= 10;
```

**Equivalente a rank(), `ranking_descontando_empates`**

```
select * from (
select
    label
    , value
    , @curRn := @curRn + 1 as row_number
from (
select
  tbl_funcionarios.nome as label
  , sum(tbl_caixa_menor.valor*-1) as value
  , (select @curRn := 0) r
from tbl_caixa_menor, tbl_funcionarios
where tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios = tbl_funcionarios.cod_funcionarios
  and tbl_caixa_menor.empresa = 'MAT'
  and date_format(tbl_caixa_menor.dataTransacao, '%Y-%m-01') = date_add((select max(date(concat(ano, '-', lpad(mes, 2, '0'), '-01'))) from tbl_caixa_saldo where empresa = 'MAT'), interval 1 month)
group by tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios, tbl_funcionarios.nome
having sum(tbl_caixa_menor.valor) < 0
order by value desc
) a
) b
where value >= (
select value from (
select
    label
    , value
    , @curRn := @curRn + 1 as row_number
from (
select
  tbl_funcionarios.nome as label
  , sum(tbl_caixa_menor.valor*-1) as value
  , (select @curRn := 0) r
from tbl_caixa_menor, tbl_funcionarios
where tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios = tbl_funcionarios.cod_funcionarios
  and tbl_caixa_menor.empresa = 'MAT'
  and date_format(tbl_caixa_menor.dataTransacao, '%Y-%m-01') = date_add((select max(date(concat(ano, '-', lpad(mes, 2, '0'), '-01'))) from tbl_caixa_saldo where empresa = 'MAT'), interval 1 month)
group by tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios, tbl_funcionarios.nome
having sum(tbl_caixa_menor.valor) < 0
order by value desc
) a
) b
where row_number = 10
);
```

**Equivalente a dense_rank() `ranking_sem_desconto_de_empates`**

```
select * from (
select
    label
    , value
    , @curRn := @curRn + 1 as row_number
from (
select
  tbl_funcionarios.nome as label
  , sum(tbl_caixa_menor.valor*-1) as value
  , (select @curRn := 0) r
from tbl_caixa_menor, tbl_funcionarios
where tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios = tbl_funcionarios.cod_funcionarios
  and tbl_caixa_menor.empresa = 'MAT'
  and date_format(tbl_caixa_menor.dataTransacao, '%Y-%m-01') = date_add((select max(date(concat(ano, '-', lpad(mes, 2, '0'), '-01'))) from tbl_caixa_saldo where empresa = 'MAT'), interval 1 month)
group by tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios, tbl_funcionarios.nome
having sum(tbl_caixa_menor.valor) < 0
order by value desc
) a
) b
where value >= (
select value from (
select 
  value
  , @curRn := @curRn + 1 as row_number
from (
select distinct
  sum(tbl_caixa_menor.valor*-1) as value
  , (select @curRn := 0) r
from tbl_caixa_menor, tbl_funcionarios
where tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios = tbl_funcionarios.cod_funcionarios
  and tbl_caixa_menor.empresa = 'MAT'
  and date_format(tbl_caixa_menor.dataTransacao, '%Y-%m-01') = date_add((select max(date(concat(ano, '-', lpad(mes, 2, '0'), '-01'))) from tbl_caixa_saldo where empresa = 'MAT'), interval 1 month)
group by tbl_caixa_menor.cod_funcionarios, tbl_funcionarios.nome
having sum(tbl_caixa_menor.valor) < 0
order by value desc
) a
) b
where row_number = 10
);
```